# With respect to what does a Gyroscope maintain its orientation?

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws, inertial-frames, gyroscopes

Assume ideal conditions, no friction, no energy loss in any form.

Just an ideal gyro, in ideal conditions, spun into rotation and left alone. And placed somewhere on earth.

From what I've read so far, it should maintain its orientation, with gimbals rotating as to maintain the orientation of the disc/plate.

But maintain its orientation with respect to what? That's the part that I can't absorb. I've seen an answer that says, "with respect to fixed stars"

I just don't understand how is that relevant at all. Even if we can't see their movement easily, doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. So I don't understand how is that a good reference point.

It doesn't have to be a gyro. It can be a Foucault pendulum on north pole.

Answer (score 9):

A gyroscope maintains its orientation with respect to any inertial reference frame. An inertial reference frame is one in which objects with no force on them remain at rest or in uniform motion (i.e., moving in a straight line with constant velocity).

Comment: This is circular reasoning. We have the following property of Euclidean space: position vectors, velocity vectors and acceleration vectors can be decomposed in perpendicular components, and for all component motion the laws of motion hold good. Circular motion can be decomposed in two perpendicular components, each a harmonic oscillation along a straight line. This answer boils down to: "Objects moving in a straight line maintain their orientation with respect to any inertial reference frame. An inertial reference frame is one in which objects move in a straight line."

Comment: Yes, Newton’s First Law defines inertial reference frames. No, my answer is not circular because the atoms of a gyroscope do not move in a straight line with uniform velocity.

Comment: As long as we are critiquing each others’ answers, I will say that I couldn’t get past your first statement that “the reference of the gyroscope is inertia.” What is a gyroscope’s “reference”?

Comment: The motion law F=ma describes the *nature of inertia*: accceleration with respect to an inertial coordinate system is proportional to exerted force. For a solar system: when you map all motion with respect to an inertial coordinate system then Kepler's laws of planetary motion obtain, otherwise they don't. More generalized: only if you use an inertial coordinate system to describe motion is it that you can obtain laws of motion, otherwise not. The observation whether laws of motion obtain or not provides an unambiguous criterium to distinguish inertial from non-inertial coordinate systems.

Comment: Stackexchange strongly urges against protracted discussion in comments. I am eager to discuss this subject. Can we move this thread to chat?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the reference of the gyroscope is inertia

As we know, inertia is that a force is required to change the velocity of an object.

In order to throw a weight you have to exert a force on it, changing it's velocity.

The thing about inertia is that it is *the same* everywhere. At *every point in space* the same force results in the same amount of change of velocity.

Just try to imagine how the world would feel if inertia would would be randomly different from moment to moment, and from place to place. Then motion would be totally unpredictable.

But motion is very predictable, and from that we infer that inertia is the same, *everywhere* and in *every direction*.

This uniformity allows inertia to be a completely effective reference of motion.

**what you can and cannot measure**

As we know, you cannot measure what your *position* in space is, because space is featureless.
You cannot measure what your *velocity* with respect to space is.

But what you *can* do is continuously measure what your *acceleration* is, and you can continuously measure whether your orientation in space is changing or not.

Velocity is the time derivative of position, acceleration is the time derivative of velocity. As we know: taking a derivative is a reversable operation (up to a constant)

With your acceleration and your orientation measured continuously you can retrace your path, kind of like walking back in you own footsteps. The fact that continuous logging of your acceleration will allow you to retrace your path demonstrates that inertia is an effective reference of motion

**The Universe**

We assume that everywhere in the Universe inertia is *the same*

It seems reasonable to assume that a spinning gyroscope remains in the same orientation with respect to the distant stars because in all of the Universe inertia is uniform.

---

**The equivalence class of inertial ccordinate systems**

The effectiveness of inertia to provide a universal reference for motion is referred to as 'the equivalence class of inertial coordinate systems'.

If you have a space and you want to assign a coordinate system to that space then the zero point of the coordinate system can be assigned to any point in that space. All of those coordinate systems are equivalent.

You can do a transformation that transforms a coordinate system to one that is oriented at a different angle. All of those coordinate systems are equivalent.

You can do a transformation that transforms a coordinate system to one that is moving with a uniform velocity to it. All of those coordinate systems are equivalent.

The members of that equivalence class have in common that there is no measurement that can single out one among that class as different from the others.

As we know: this equivalence does not extend to acceleration. The physical properties of inertia are the reference for the distinction between the members of the equivalence class of inertial coordinate sytems, and non-inertial coordinate systems.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I've just rewritten the answer, focussing on the universality of inertia.

Comment: That's much better!